# Что такое css selector level?

Tags: css

Читаю [статью](https://www.quackit.com/css/selectors/)  про список css селекторов,  объясните пожалуйста что значит  css level  и почему в таблице из статьи разные селекторы имеют различный level ?

Comment: level в данном случае версия `css`. На сегодняшний день актуален `css3`

Comment: css обновляют не весь сразу, а по модулям которым присваивают уровень. В каждом новом модуле свои дополнения и новинки функционала.